# Finding Duplicate Rows in a Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out how many duplicate records I have in a table. I can use count, but I'm not sure how best to eliminate records where the count is only 1.

```
select first_name, last_name, start_date, count(1)
from employee
group by first_name, last_name, start_date;
```

I can try to order by the count, but I am still not eliminating those with a count of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `having` clause as `having Count(*) > 1` after `group by` like this :

```
select 
  first_name, 
  last_name, 
  start_date,
  Count(*) AS Count
from 
  employee 
group by 
  first_name, 
  last_name, 
  start_date
having 
  Count(*) > 1
```